# How do I replace non word characters with a dash using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I replace the characters `~!@#$%^&*()_+}{][` in a `nvarchar` (or `varchar`) field with a `-` using TSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create user define function for that as given below

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_ReplaceSpecialChar
(
@inputString VARCHAR(1000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @outputString VARCHAR(1000),
            @LENGTH INT,
            @index INT,
            @char CHAR(1)
    SELECT @LENGTH = LEN(@inputString),
           @index = 1
    WHILE(@index <= @LENGTH)
    BEGIN
        SET @char = SUBSTRING(@inputString, @index, 1)
        IF((ASCII(@char) NOT BETWEEN 65 AND 90) AND (ASCII(@char) NOT BETWEEN 97 AND 122) AND (ASCII(@char) NOT BETWEEN 48 AND 57))
        BEGIN
            SELECT @inputString = REPLACE(@inputString, @char, '-')
        END
        SET @index = @index + 1
    END 
    SET @outputString = @inputString
    RETURN @outputString
END

SELECT dbo.udf_ReplaceSpecialChar('This()*& is%%@Sample**.>String')
```

or you should replace each character with '-'
Like

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('This()*& is%%@Sample**.>String', ' ', '-'), '*', '-'), '@', '-'), '&', '-'), '(', '-'), ')', '-'), '.', '-'), '>', '-'), '%', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function.  If it doesn't work in some cases, please give us examples.

May be [this code](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/mssql/1.htm) is that you are searching for:

```
-- Author: Christian d'Heureuse, www.source-code.biz
create function dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@s varchar(256)) returns varchar(256)
   with schemabinding
begin
   if @s is null
      return null
   declare @s2 varchar(256)
   set @s2 = ''
   declare @l int
   set @l = len(@s)
   declare @p int
   set @p = 1
   while @p <= @l begin
      declare @c int
      set @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))
      if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122
         set @s2 = @s2 + char(@c)
      set @p = @p + 1
      end
   if len(@s2) = 0
      return null
   return @s2
   end
```

It removes all characters except 0-9, a-z and A-Z.  This function uses ASCII codes of characters to determine this ones which must be removed.

Comment: May be this code is what you are searching http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/mssql/1.htm

Comment: Dear I have also searched lots of solutions .... this example is removing all the special characters.... but I want to replace not remove all special characters. And my text is in table column.

Comment: All you need - rewrite this line `if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122` to include characters you need to remove

Comment: Moreover, you can remove last part of this condition and this function will be doing exactly what you need `~!@#$%^&*()_+}{][.... all except numbers and characters a-z`. If you want to keep A-Z too, just left it as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
--another one variant    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --better to keep such table in server, very usefull table, especially with indexes 
    DECLARE @Tally TABLE ( N INT ) 
    DECLARE  @i AS INT = 1
    WHILE @i != 1000 
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @Tally
                    ( N )
            VALUES  ( @i )
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(1000) = 'This()*& is%%@ **.>another one //&^&*$variant'
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --using @tally - split, using like - remove not required, 'for xml ...' - combine into string 
    SELECT  REPLACE(( SELECT    LEFT(SUBSTRING(@String, n, 1000), 1)
                      FROM      @Tally AS T
                      WHERE     SUBSTRING(@String, n, 1000) != ''
                                AND LEFT(SUBSTRING(@String, n, 1000), 1) LIKE '[A-Za-z0-9 ]'
                    FOR
                      XML PATH('')
                    ), '&#X20;', ' ')
```

Comment: This one is alsow working... This is returning :This is another one variant

How to replace spaces with dashes so that it look like:
This-is-another-one-variant

Comment: Got it just changed last line '&#X20;', ' ')
to this 
'&#X20;', '-')

This is best than the first one... I wish I have got this one before :(

Comment: @MaxPayne, I will post another variant, I think that better than in my previous post, it used currently as a function in our SQL server

Answer (score 0):

```
    --another one variant    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    --better to keep such table in server, very usefull table, especially with indexes 
      DECLARE @Tally TABLE ( N INT ) 
      DECLARE @i AS INT = 1
      WHILE @i != 1000 
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @Tally
                    ( N )
            VALUES  ( @i )
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      DECLARE @String VARCHAR(500) ,
        @B VARCHAR(500) = '' 
      SET @String = 'This()*& is%%@ **.>another one //&^&*$variant'

      SELECT    @B = @B + SUBSTRING(@String, t.N, 1)
      FROM      @Tally t
      WHERE     t.N <= DATALENGTH(@String)
                AND PATINDEX('[A-Za-z0-9 ]', SUBSTRING(@String, t.N, 1)) > 0

      SELECT    @B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> if you wish use this method like a function then:
>
> 1. Create Tally table with one field PRIMARY KEY (1000 rows, starting from 1 with step 1)
> 2. Use code below to create function
>
> Table Tally will be very useful for the split sting, clean string etc., currently this is 
>   the best way to use instead fetch, xml and etc.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StringClean]( 
    @A VARCHAR(500)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(500) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @B VARCHAR(500)
SET @B = ''
SELECT  @B = @B + SUBSTRING(@A, t.N, 1)
FROM    dbo.Tally t
WHERE   t.N <= DATALENGTH(@A)
        AND PATINDEX('[A-Za-z0-9 ]', SUBSTRING(@A, t.N, 1)) > 0
RETURN @B
END
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT  dbo.StringClean('This()*& is%%@ **.>another one //&^&*$variant')
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @Tally TABLE ( N INT ) 
    DECLARE  @i AS INT = 1
    WHILE @i != 1000 
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO @Tally (N) VALUES  (@i)
            SET @i = @i + 1
        END
--------------------------------------------------------------
    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(500) 
    DECLARE @B VARCHAR(500) = '' 
    DECLARE @ReplacedChars VARCHAR(50) = '~!@#$%^&*()_+}{][<>/.'
    SET @String = 'This()*& is%%@ **.>another one //&^&*$variant'
    SELECT  @B = @B + CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@String, t.N, 1), @ReplacedChars) > 0 THEN '-'
                           ELSE SUBSTRING(@String, t.N, 1) END
    FROM    @Tally t
    WHERE   t.N <= DATALENGTH(@String)
    SELECT  @B
```